# How to change the legend text of a chart in a crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, legend

hey I'm working on winforms c#,

How can I change the legend text of a chart object in a crystal report?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open report in Crystal Reports.
2. Set report to “Preview Mode” by clicking View -> Print Preview
3. When in “Preview Mode”, select the Legend label you want to change the text of.
4. Right click on the Legend label and select “Edit Axis Label”
5. Then, select the chart, right click and select Chart Expert -> Apply to group template.
6. Save the modified report!

Hope this helps to resolve your problem.

Comment: I can't do this coz I don't have the full version. Is there any other way to do this?